# How do I make sure a string column has no spaces?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have currently a primary key field of `nvarchar(50)`, I am willing to change the type, if I can get it to accept no white space.  Is there anyway to do this?

**Should allow the following:**

```
------
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

**Should not allow the following:**

```
------
AA AAA
BBBB B
C CCCC
```

Comment: CHECK ( CHARINDEX(key_column,' ') = 0 )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could add the following check constraint:

<strike>`CHECK LEN(col) = LEN(REPLACE(col, ' ', ''));`</strike>

...or...

```
CHECK (col NOT LIKE '% %');
```

...or...

```
CHECK (CHARINDEX(' ', col) = 0)
```

Example:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.bar(foo NVARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY);

ALTER TABLE dbo.bar ADD CONSTRAINT chkNoSpaces
 CHECK (foo NOT LIKE '% %');
```

Succeeds:

```
INSERT dbo.bar(foo) SELECT 'AAAA';
GO
```

Fails:

```
INSERT dbo.bar(foo) SELECT 'AA AA';
GO
```

Results:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 
> The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "chkNoSpaces". The conflict occurred in
>   database "tempdb", table "dbo.bar", column 'foo'. 
> The statement has
>   been terminated.

Clean up:

```
DROP TABLE dbo.bar;
```

**EDIT**

If you need to do this through the UI for some reason (again I recommend you do this with a script that you can make atomic, repeatable, save to a file, store in source control, etc):

1. In Object Explorer, right-click your table and select <kbd>Design</kbd>
2. Right-click your column in the upper grid and select <kbd>Check Constraints...</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
4. Type `column_name NOT LIKE '% %'` in the "Expression" box (use your actual column name, not `column_name`)
5. If you think you already have data that violates the constraint, change the option for "Check Existing Data..." to <kbd>No</kbd> (and promptly go fix that data)
6. Click <kbd>Close</kbd>
7. Click on the "Save" icon on the toolbar

Note that the UI actually changes the construction of the clause, e.g. `(NOT col_name LIKE '% %')`

Comment: Is there anyway to do this in Managment Studio?

Comment: Yes but it's convoluted to walk through all of the UI dialogs. It's also something you can't save in a script or source control. Why do you need to use Management Studio to do this?

Comment: Why not?: CHECK CHARINDEX(N' ',col) = 0

I like the trick of comparing these lengths to count occurrences, but it seems like the CHARINDEX should only have to scan the string once (at most) and the REPLACE and two LENs seem more expensive without knowing the internals.

Comment: Ok, I will give this a try.  Thanks.  I will approve this answer when it's available.

Comment: @GilM your CHARINDEX and my LIKE are going to be identical. Also unless you are inserting thousands of primary key values every minute it is unlikely you will ever see the performance difference. I'll add charindex as a 3rd option.

Comment: I just realized that you may be trying to allow trailing spaces.  I didn't get that requirement from the text or examples.

Comment: Option 1 (LEN) allows trailing spaces.  Options 2 (LIKE) and 3 (CHARINDEX) don't.

Comment: @GilM ah I see. Rather inconsequential because the trailing space is ignored on future inserts (try inserting `'BBBB '` and then `'BBBB'`). And who intentionally puts trailing spaces in their primary keys anyway?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, but just thought I'd call it out so that the poster is aware of the actual behavior.  I've been bitten by the trimming "feature" of LEN, so an alarm goes off in my head whenever I see it.